# The actual function or effect of `boot=` in grub

Tags: grub2

What is the function or effect of `boot=` in grub entry as it's found sometimes one of

```
 boot=live 
 boot=casper
```

How is it different if its not extant ?

Comment: Did you take a look at [the documentation](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/en/man8/initramfs-tools.8.html#boot%20scripts)?

Answer (score 2):

Those are normally specified as *Linux kernel boot parameters*. Since `boot=` is not a parameter recognized by the actual kernel, the parameter is just displayed in `/proc/cmdline`. From there, the initramfs or any distribution-specific scripts can read it and do whatever they want with it.

`boot=casper` is specifically used by Debian/Ubuntu live boot media to trigger an initramfs procedure specific for live boot media, i.e. instead of mounting a regular root filesystem, set up a root filesystem based on read-only filesystem image + either a RAM disk or a separately specified "persistence" partition/image file. The special live media boot procedure also makes available a number of other boot parameters that might not be available otherwise, to e.g. specify the system network configuration by kernel boot parameters.

If persistence is not enabled, any changes to the root filesystem are applied to RAM only, and will be lost on reboot. With persistence, the specified persistence partition/image will only contain any changes relative to the read-only root filesystem image, which may then be stored on CD/DVD or any other read-only media: only the persistence partition/image will need writeable storage.

Documentation regarding `boot=casper`: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man7/casper.7.html

`boot=live` is probably used by some other distributions for similar purposes.

Having a special boot option to trigger live media procedures allows using the same live media to also boot to a regular writeable root filesystem from an external media, to e.g. recover a damaged bootloader.

Not all live Linux distributions will require such boot option: it is also possible to build an initramfs so that it is hard-coded to work as live media boot only.